# Java program hangs on joining a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm making a simple chat program using sockets, and I have an ArrayList to store active objected classes with sockets and usernames for each connected client, and inside those classes it checks if the socket is still open, and calls for its self to be joined if it is not.

Server file kick code:

```
public synchronized void kick(ClientThread client){
    try{
        output.printLine("kicking " + client.getUsername());
        clients.remove(client);
        output.printLine("removed " + client.getUsername());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    output.printLine("kicked ");
}
```

This is what is called by the client object if its socket is closed.

clients being the ArrayList which stores the clients

client being the class object which I want to join, the client object extends Thread

```
public void run(){

    while(true){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
            if(isValid()){
                /*bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                if(bufferedReader.ready()){
                    lastMsg = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    sendMessage("Hello");
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }*/
            }else{
                output.printLine(this.getUsername() + " connection closed");
                break;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    server.kick(this);
    try {
        join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    output.printLine("joined " + getUsername());
}
```

This is the run function from the client object, at the bottom is the code which is run when the socket is not connected, it breaks from the loop and should join its self, however it hangs on joining its self. The client is removed from the ArrayList properly but no matter what i do i cannot get the thread to join.

Comment: _should join its self_ What do you think that means?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work. To `join` a thread means waiting until it died. If you wait for yourself to die, you will wait forever, because as long as you wait you cannot die.

Comment: I wish it were that easy to fool death :P

Comment: I thought it was a case of join ception D: do you know how I can join this thread without it hanging?

Comment: Depends on how you define join. As I said, you cannot join yourself as joining in this context means waiting for the thread to die and while you wait you cannot die.

Answer (score 0):

> if the socket is still open, and calls for its self to be joined if it is not.

A thread cannot call for itself to be joined.  If a thread wants to quit then it just returns from the `run()` method.  *Other* threads that are waiting for that thread to die can call `thread.join()` on it.  But as @Vampire pointed out, for a thread to call `this.join()` will mean that it is waiting for itself to finish but it never will because it is waiting for itself to finish.  Joinception indeed.

> but no matter what i do i cannot get the thread to join.

I think the question here is what are you trying to achieve.  If you want the thread to finish then just return from the `run()` method.  If you are trying to notify other threads that you are finishing then they should do the `join`-ing.